# as3 URLRequest and file stream saving xml data - Error #3013: File or directory is in use

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, filestream

My end goal is to open an xml file, change data and save it. I am opening it with a URLRequest. I am able to change the xml, however, MY ISSUE IS: **When I try to open it with a stream to save the file then it says:**

```
Error: Error #3013: File or directory is in use.
```

I suppose I could open it with the same stream but then I don't know how to get the xml vars like I do in my script when I am using the URLRequest.

So I either need to a) close the xml file so I can open it with a stream or b) open the xml with a stream and some how get the vars I need and manipulate them for saving.  There may be a c) but I can't think of it now.

Here is my code:

```
package com
{
    import flash.filesystem.*;
    import flash.system.System;

    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.display.*;


    public class userSettings
    {

        public var pathToFile:String = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('userSettings.xml').nativePath;
        public var someFile:File = new File(pathToFile);
        public var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();



        public var myLoader = new URLLoader();

        public function userSettings()
        {
            loadSettings();
        }

        public function saveSettings(daFile:String)
        {
            stream.open(someFile, FileMode.WRITE);
            stream.writeUTFBytes(daFile);
            trace("Settings SAVED! " +daFile);
            //stream.close();
        }




public function loadSettings()
        {




            trace(pathToFile);


            myLoader.load(new URLRequest(pathToFile));


            myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

            function processXML(e:Event):void
            {
                var myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

                // Gets vars from xml. I need this option. 
                var homeT = myXML.Settings.(@Title=="homeT");
                trace("And it works? " + homeT);

                            // Changes vars in xml                   
                            myXML.Settings.(@Title == "homeT").* = "Home2";

                // trace works with changed xml
                             trace(myXML);
                            /// Now trying to save it doesn't work. 
                saveSettings(myXML);
            }

        }


/////////
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far I as know you could just read the bytes from the stream, something like:

```
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ); 
var myXML:XML = XML(fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable));
```

Then you have an XML object that you can manipulate as you did in your example.

Comment: How do add an event listener to it then? Also, I can't seem to get the vars using this method when I put an trace(myXML); after your code.

Comment: This one is killing me. I am so close. I just need to write the xml but a file stream to that file is already open.

Comment: This is a synchrounous call, so there is no need of the listener. If you want to open it asynchronously, you should check FileStream openAsync.

Comment: ah ok. Why is the trace(myXML); empty then? :(

Comment: Are you sure you are opening it from the correct location (trace(someFile.exists);) with the correct FileMode and that the XML is actually not empty?

Comment: ok, I got it to work. However, I am getting the SAME ERROR when trying to save it with the fuction saveSettings(myXML); It is saying the directory is already open. :(

Comment: I am not getting any error on my mac so I assume this is a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238601/adobe-air-filestream-error-3013-file-or-directory-is-in-use

Comment: So you are using the full code and not getting an error? The file userSettings.as is saved to my desktop. I am looking into the links you sent.

Comment: Ok... THAT IS RIDICULOUS... it was that I needed a few milliseconds to wait to write the file again, on windows only. wow! I would have never figured that one out without your help. Thank you sooo much!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

A slight delay is needed BEFORE using the FileStream class to open, write, close. Again, Windows only!  I used a timer to call the function that writes to the location.

The answer can was found on this link: [Adobe Air FileStream Error #3013: File or directory is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238601/adobe-air-filestream-error-3013-file-or-directory-is-in-use)